# Insert record to Hive table from Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to insert records into `Hive` table from `Spark`(`Scala`). The values that I am trying to insert are structured data that come as a case class.

Here is what I have:

```
case class rcd(
  request: Int,
  extract_id: Int)
}
```

Then:

```
DF.as[rcd].take(DF.count.toInt).foreach(e => { // DF is a dataframe that contains data

if <condition> {
       ss.sql(s"""INSERT INTO mytable select $e.request ,'$e.extract_id'""")
}
```

I am getting an error:

> Undefined function: 'rcd'. This function is neither a registered
>   temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database
>   'default'.;

Also, what is the `'default'` that `Spark` mentioned in the previous message

Any comments will be appreciated

Comment: You shouldn't do a foreach on a take, just bulk insert using rdd.toDf.write.mode("append").insertInto("table")
The default database is the one created by default, meaning you didn't mentionned a specific one to insert to

Answer (score 1):

Did you register your udf function?

If not please register the udf function with the SQLContext's UDF Registry.

```
sqlContext.udf.register("RCD", rcd)
```